# Virtual Attribute Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to create an attribute on my model that took in a symbol for ascending or descending.  However, RoR does not allow enumerated types in the database, so I created a boolean property and then added an attribute on my model.  This works great for everything except validations, which I can't seem to get to work.  `container.valid?` always returns true, even when `order` hasn't been set.Any ideas?

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :score_order
  validates :order, :presence => true

  def order
    return order_ascends ? :ascending : :descending
  end

  def order=(order)
    case order
    when :ascending
        self.order_ascends = true
    when :descending
        self.order_ascends = false
    else
        throw :unexpected_argument
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to validate order_ascends:

```
1: it is present
2: it is a boolean
```

The order method is just what you're using to interface to order_ascends.

Comment: Hmm, that make sense but `valid?` is still returning true.

Comment: Whoops, I was just being stupid and looking at the wrong test.  Thanks for the help.